# Do I need Ambassador if I use Istio for Mapping?

Tags: kubernetes, mapping, istio, ambassador

I have been using Ambassador for a while, I like it but it's been spamming my logs with `GET /api/.ambassador-internal/openapi-docs`. So I'm thinking to switch to another mapping alternative and I found Istio. I'm not sure what exactly what is yet, but seems like I can use it to replace ambassador mapping.

So my question is that if I use Istio do I even need Ambassador?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ambassador](https://github.com/datawire/ambassador) is essentially a Kubernetes ingress controller/API gateway that uses [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/).

And Istio is a service mesh that happens to have its own [ingress mechanism](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/), and Istio also uses Envoy as sidecar proxies. So in a way yes, you can replace Ambassador with Istio, but you may not be able to get the API gateway type of features with Istio. [This blog](https://blog.christianposta.com/microservices/do-i-need-an-api-gateway-if-i-have-a-service-mesh/) explains the differences and attempts to clarify the confusion.

I'm not really sure that Istio is going to help you with the logs since it looks like the issue that you are seeing with log spamming is related to the API gateway component. It really depends on how you architect your application/services.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Seems like the openapi-docs issue has been solved https://github.com/datawire/ambassador/issues/2619. So I'm ok with using ambassador now. But seems like Ambassador has many features to learn and cover. Since I want to keep things as simple as possible, based on your answer, if I use ambassador just for Mapping, can I replace it with just using Envoy?